# Pymongo array field: Guaranteed to have its elements stay in the order

Tags: pymongo

Python ensures to have list elements to stay in the order.

As I understand, MongoDB arrays also keeps the order of the array.

**Using Pymongo also ensures the same order when inserting, retrieving and updating?**

I do not have big reasons for doubt of that, but I can't find any reference about it!

pymongo==3.3.1

MongoDB 3.4.9

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/index.html provides the mapping of python types to BSON types. Since both sides maintain order, insertion, retrieval etc should maintain order.

Since python dicts do not maintain key order, the BSON package also provides http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/son.html 
In case array order wasn't getting maintained, they probably would have provided some tool to deal with it too